# How can i search if argv ends with a char

Tags: c

How would i check to see if argv ends with a character? for example how would i write the program if I wanted to see if the agv[1] ends with the character z.

```
if(argv[1] == ? )
    printf("The input entered ends with the character z");
```

Comment: Hint:: strlen, strcmp

Comment: how would you check if any of the characters in `argv[1]` were `z`?  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_strings.htm

Comment: Another hint:: Check if you have any argument passed. If yes, find the length. If found, try going to the last char of that string. If reached, just do simple `==` comparison to `'z'` to see if it ends with 'z'.

Comment: Voting to close this question.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  int string_length;

  if(argc < 2)
    printf("\n no arguments \n");
  else if(argc > 1)
    {
      string_length = strlen(argv[1]);
      if(argv[1][string_length - 1] == 'z')
        printf("\n The input entered ends with the character z \n");
      else
        printf("\n The input entered ends without the character z \n");
    }
}
```